# How do I get Second Life for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: games

I have downloaded the Second Life package for Ubuntu 14.04 but I am unsure how to run it. What file do I have to click on to set it up?

[image: Second Life Folder]

Comment: "download"? you click a link (...). Or did you mean "play second life on Ubuntu"?c

Comment: @Rinzwind I meant how to play Secondlife on ubuntu sorry I didnt phrase it properly

Comment: https://secondlife.com/support/downloads/

Comment: @ScottStensland I tried downloading it but how do I set it up

Comment: You'll need to prove further explanation as to why it didn't work.

Comment: @Brian I dont why it doesn't work. I followed a tutorial on how to do it and it doesn't start when I try to start the game. Is there any way I can delete it and try again?

Comment: What video hardware do you have (SecondLife is pretty video intensive). Voice chat was let die for Linux users awhile ago, so don't waste time trying to get that to work. Unpack the dowload and run the secondlife from the top level, nothing else to do if you're not trying to install.

Comment: @ubfan1 I unbpacked it , what do I do now? Included a screenshot of the unpacked file

Answer (score 7):

SL is a 32 bit binary so if you are on 64 bit (which everyone is at this point) here is what I just did

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxext6:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio:i386 libidn11:i386 libuuid1:i386 libstdc++6:i386
sudo apt-get install libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386
sudo apt-get install libwebkit-dev libaprutil1-dev  libtcnative-1
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libogg-dev libpng12-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libgtk2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libopenal-dev libvorbis-dev libalut-dev libapr1-dev libaprutil1-dev libboost-dev libc-ares-dev libxmlrpc-epi-dev libopenjpeg-dev libjpeg62-dev libgtk2.0-dev libsdl1.2-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev google-mock
sudo apt-get install libdb-dev  libapr1-dev libaprutil1-dev
sudo apt-get install libopenal1:i386
```

Above did the trick to get the window to launch ... above is a superset ... some are to compile not just to execute binary

... then to get sound working follow [go here to get sound working](https://community.secondlife.com/forums/topic/364619-linux-upgrade-to-secondlife-viewer-401-how-i-got-it-working/?tab=comments#comment-1579675)

which does get sound working ... once launched the SL window will show popup saying

```
We're having trouble connecting to your voice server :
    https://.....
    :UDP: 3478, 3479, 5060, 5062, 12000-17000
Voice communications will not be available.
Please check your network and firewall setup
```

which is blocking ability to use voice chat ... if desired you need to open up UDP port(s)   as in

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp  --dport 3478 -j ACCEPT
```

In other words ... SL is not usable out of the box !!! however it runs fine using above steps

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal, unpack the file, and cd into the resulting directory, which has a name like Second_Life_3_8_2_i686, and contains:

```
app_settings  etc                     install.sh    README-linux-joystick.txt  res-sdl              skins
bin           featuretable_linux.txt  lib           README-linux.txt           secondlife           summary.json
character     fonts                   licenses.txt  README-linux-voice.txt     secondlife_icon.png
```

Run the program in the terminal by typing ./secondlife

Comment: How do I do that, Im a noob at this. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Press ctrl+alt+T. In the terminal window that opens, enter `cd ~/Second*686` then enter `./secondlife`

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands:

```
wget http://download.cloud.secondlife.com/Viewer_4/Second_Life_4_0_4_314579_i686.tar.bz2
tar xvf Second_Life*
cd Second_Life*
sudo ./install.sh
```

Refer to the readme files for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing this myself just now. I downloaded the package and extracted the files, and ran `./secondlife` from the extracted directory.

This is the output:

```
aspire:~/SecondLife/Second_Life_4_0_4_314579_i686$ ./secondlife
64-bit Linux detected.
Multi-arch support detected.
Running from /home/grace/SecondLife/Second_Life_4_0_4_314579_i686
 - Installing menu entries in /home/grace/.local/share/applications
bin/do-not-directly-run-secondlife-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libfreetype.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
*** Bad shutdown ($LL_RUN_ERR). ***

You are running the Second Life Viewer on a x86_64 platform.  The
most common problems when launching the Viewer (particularly
'bin/do-not-directly-run-secondlife-bin: not found' and 'error while
loading shared libraries') may be solved by installing your Linux
distribution's 32-bit compatibility packages.
For example, on Ubuntu and other Debian-based Linuxes you might run:
$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs ia32-libs-gtk ia32-libs-kde ia32-libs-sdl

*******************************************************
This is a BETA release of the Second Life linux client.
Thank you for testing!
Please see README-linux.txt before reporting problems.

aspire:~/SecondLife/Second_Life_4_0_4_314579_i686$
```

So clearly the problem is exactly what Scott Stensland said it was, which is that you are trying to run a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit architecture. You have to install a compatibility package. You could start with what it suggests and enter these in the terminal (ctrl+alt+T to open a terminal window):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs ia32-libs-gtk ia32-libs-kde ia32-libs-sdl
```

But looks like you will have to do all the steps that Scott suggested to get it to work. Not easy.